# I'm experiencing an issue when I click a button inside a WebView in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

**Context:**

I have a React Native application and it has a WebView component that renders a map. (That map is an external React application, so when I talk about it, think in an external application based on React)

This app is executed on an Android tablet.

I've created a button inside that map in order to get a 'center map' functionality.

**Issue:**

When I click the button, an strange error appears:

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'RegExp')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'RegExp')
    at $o.i (http://192.168.0.15:3000/static/js/bundle.js:14554:132)
```

I've tried to find that error on code but bundle.js has obfuscated code and it's impossible to know what is happening.

I've tried to change 'onClick' method by 'onPress' but I've obtained the same result.

**Code:**

This is the most revelant part (webview) because the button on the map only has a console log.

```
<WebView
    ref={webviewRef}
    onMessage={event => {
      if (
        event.nativeEvent.data &&
        event.nativeEvent.data === 'mapLoaded'
      ) {
        setmapLoaded(true);
      }
    }}
    source={{
      uri: 'http://192.168.0.15:3000/',
    }}
    onError={(error)=>{console.log(error)}}
  />
```

Well, the obfuscated code and the main problem is:

```
 $o.prototype.i = function (a) {
    var b = a.type,
      c = vo(this.f);
    c = {
      x: a.pageX - c.x,
      y: a.pageY - c.y
    };
    var d;
    (d = this.a.a[0] || null) || (d = new xo(c.x, c.y, 1, "mouse"), this.a.push(d));
    this.b.push(d);
    yo(d, c.x, c.y);
    /^mouse(?:move|over|out)$/.test(b) ? Ko(this, "pointermove", a) : (/^mouse(down|up)$/.test(b) && (c = a.which - 1, "up" === wo.RegExp.$1 ? Bo(d, c) : zo(d, c)), Ko(this, b.replace("mouse", "pointer"), a));
    this.b.clear();
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have sufficient reputation to leave a comment, I'm posting this as an answer instead. I hope it provides some assistance. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onmessage) on onMessage, this function is triggered when the webview invokes window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage. Are you using a postMessage method in your web code?

Comment: Yes I am using window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage, but this method is used in the web application when the map is loaded, after that the webview component gets that information using onMessage listener. 

The button which I have problem only works with the web app logic, It doesn't need to send information to the native application.